# IValueConverter – Passing an object as ConverterParameter

Tags: xaml, xamarin

In my Xamarin xaml file I have a ProgressBar, where I need to compute Progress (Value/Maximum). So I wrote my Convertor, but I am not able to pass the Maximum to the Convertor.

I tried to use ConverterParameter, but it does not support bindings...

```
<ProgressBar Progress="{Binding Progress.Value, 
    Converter={StaticResource Convertor}, ConverterParameter=??}" />
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a reference directly into your converter if it's defined in xaml of whatever class/ViewModel that has all the values you need to calculate progress.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="_progressBar" Progress="{Binding Progress.Value,
    Converter={StaticResource Convertor}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference _progressBar}}" />
```

or you could just pass in the value directly in xaml or as a static value defined in a static class from elsewhere in your app, which is of course if you know what the value will be ahead of time.

```
, ConverterParameter=1}" or
, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:DefaultValues.MaxValue}}"
```

However, it does sound like you could calculate Progress in your ViewModel on property changed before setting `Progress.Value`/`Progress.MaxValue` property, and then you wouldn't even need a converter.

Comment: I have the Maximum property in the Progress class and the Maximum property changes in the runtime.

Comment: Maximum is always 1, if you need to change it dynamically you should just re-calculate the `Progress` on your 'MaximumProperty` change